# Draw irregular water in 3D scene using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a plane river in my 3d scene using water element. but the course of this river is irregular , not the rectangle, seen as below picture.
[image]
and the water element is defined as

```
 water = new THREE.Water( waterGeometry, {
        color: params.color,
        scale: params.scale,
        flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2( params.flowX, params.flowY ),
        textureWidth: 1024,
        textureHeight: 1024
    } );`
```

only two parameter：length and width  is descried for the water. And how can i make a irregular water like picture showed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not up on three.js but can't you cut the river out of your image and lay the image on top of your water element rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a water pane, flat and rectangular. The world pane should have a depth, where the water can clip through it. So the terrain (the bank of the river) has to be irregular.

(Sorry for my poor drawing skills)
[image: Water]

You can create a terrain any depth and shape you want with heightmapping.

[Here is a good example](http://danni-three.blogspot.com/2013/09/threejs-heightmaps.html) how to create a terrain from heightmap.

Comment: Another option is to separate the river water geometry into a separate model and apply the water shader to that. That way you can have rivers/lakes at different altitudes.